# Need help for making the cycle-sequence of a program

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm working on a dishwasher program that can implement few modes, well like the hot water, long mode; hot water, short mode; cold water, long mode; fruit wash mode, etc.

Problem is, on my final project presentation (on design stage, not even into coding yet), I presented on how I implement this with basically real pre-wash/wash/rinse/dry cycles on a dishwasher. It was before I realized if that's actually complicating things, a lot, and unfortunately I have to implement it anyway, since I presented it like so.

Using ESP32 DEVKIT V1 DOIT here, if you're wondering.

What I got confused now, I already made how the cycles works, which below (it's incomplete, yet, and not even modified much as I don't know to implement the prewash/wash/rinse/dry cycle well).

```
switch (currProg) {
    
// set up  parameters for selected wash program:  
//water level, prewash time, wash time, wash Temperature , rinse time, rinse temp, dry time, dry Temperature
case hotFastProg:washprogconfig (high,5,15,60,10,         60,10,70); break;
case hotLongProg:washprogconfig (high,10,25,60,10,         60,10,70); break;
case coldFastProg:washprogconfig (high,5,15,60,10,         60,10,70); break;
case coldLongProg:washprogconfig (high,10,25,60,10,         60,10,70); break;
case fruitProg:washprogconfig (high,5,15,60,10,         60,10,70); break;
                    }   
//below, how we can put those parameters above to the cycles.
void washprogconfig (int inwaterLevel, int inprewashTime, int inwashTime,  float inwashTemp, int inrinseTime, float inrinseTemp, int indryTime, float indryTemp)
{ 

waterLevel = inwaterLevel;
prewashTime = inprewashTime;
washTime = inwashTime;
rinseTime = inrinseTime;
dryTime = indryTime;
washTemp = inwashTemp;
rinseTemp = inrinseTemp;
dryTemp = indryTemp;

}

//switch between cycles (drain, fill, prewash, wash, rinse, dry)
void switchmode ( int induration, String newmsg)
{ 
  String outmsg = " mode started";

    prevMode = currMode;
    startTime = timeNow;
    endTime = startTime + induration;  
    outmsg = ": " + newmsg + outmsg;

     digitalWrite (outlet,  switchOff);
     digitalWrite (washPump,  switchOff);
     digitalWrite (inlet,  switchOff);
     digitalWrite (heater,  switchOff);

     heaterStatus = false;
}

////// ------------------------- few lines of codes that's unnecesary to show (for showing text) 

// record the time
  timeNow = millis() / timingFactor;
 
  // calculate remaining progtime (to be honest, on this part I didn't get it much, it just works on the past before I modify it. hence probably it'd be wrong)

  remainProgTime = 0;

    remainProgTime += (endTime - timeNow); // remprogrime = remprogtrime + (endtime-timenow)

    switch (currMode) {
      case fillin : remainProgTime += (washTime + drainTime);
      break;
      case preWash : remainProgTime += drainTime;
      break;
      case wash : remainProgTime += drainTime;
      break;
      case rinse : remainProgTime += drainTime;
      break;
      case drain: //nothing to add
      break;    
      }
      // add the time of the remaining full cycles and the Dry Time
     remainProgTime += ( fillTime + prewashTime + washTime + rinseTime + drainTime) + dryTime;    

////// ------------------------- few lines of codes that's unnecesary to show 

//(but at least I can get it done on the cycle modes, still lots of mistake ofc tho)
 switch (currMode)
  { 
    // ----------------------------------- START
     case progStart:
    if (currMode != prevMode) {
      switchmode (0, "Program Dimulai");
    }
    currMode = drain;     
    break;

     // ------------------------------ DRAIN
    case drain: 
    if (currMode != prevMode) {
      switchmode (drainTime, "Drain");
      delay (2000);
      digitalWrite (outlet, switchOn); 
    }
    else if (waterLevel == empty || (currProg == testProg && timeNow >= endTime)) 
      { // drain completed 
      currCycle ++;
      if (currCycle <= nbrCycle) 
         currMode = fillin;
      else 
      if (dryTime > 0)
        currMode = dry;
      else
        currMode = complete;
      }
    else if (timeNow >= endTime) {          
      currMode = errPause;  //Error
    }  
    break;

    // ------------------------------ FILL
    case fillin:
    if (currMode != prevMode) {
      switchmode (fillTime, "fill");      
      digitalWrite (inlet, switchOn);  // open the inlet to let water in from the hose.
    }
    else if (waterLevel == high or (currProg == testProg and timeNow >= endTime))  
      currMode = wash;
    else if (timeNow >= endTime) {
      currMode = errPause;  // Error 
    }
     
  
    break;

    // ------------------------- PREWASH
    case prewash:

    if (currMode != prevMode)
     {
      switchmode (prewashTime, "Pre-Wash");    
      digitalWrite (washPump, switchOn);  
     }

    else if (timeNow >= endTime) 
     {
      currMode = drain;   
     }

    break;

    // ------------------------ WASH
        case wash:

    if (currMode != prevMode)
     {
      switchmode (washTime, "Wash");
      //tambah buat sabun

      digitalWrite (washPump, switchOn);  
     }

    else if (timeNow >= endTime) 
     {
      currMode = drain;   
     }


    if (washTemp > 0)
    { // turn off heater if above max. Temp.
      if ( waterTemp  >  (washTemp + marginTemp) ) {
        digitalWrite (heater, switchOff);
        heaterStatus = false;
        }
      // turn on heater if below max. Temp
      else if ( waterTemp  <  (washTemp - marginTemp) ) {
        digitalWrite (heater, switchOn);
        heaterStatus = true;
        }
    }
    break;

    // ----------------------------- RINSE
    case rinse:

    if (currMode != prevMode)
     {
      switchmode (rinseTime, "Rinse");    
      digitalWrite (washPump, switchOn);  
     }

    else if (timeNow >= endTime) 
     {
      currMode = drain;   
     }


    if (rinseTemp > 0)
    { // turn off heater if above max. Temp.
      if ( waterTemp  >  (rinseTemp + marginTemp) ) {
        digitalWrite (heater, switchOff);
        heaterStatus = false;
        }
      // turn on heater if below max. Temp
      else if ( waterTemp  <  (rinseTemp - marginTemp) ) {
        digitalWrite (heater, switchOn);
        heaterStatus = true;
        }
    }
    break;
    
    //------------------------------- DRY
   case dry:

   if (currMode != prevMode) {
      switchmode (dryTime, "Dry");      
    }

    else if (timeNow >= endTime) 
        currMode = complete;

    if (dryTemp > 0)
    { // turn off heater if above max. Temp.
      if ( waterTemp  >  (dryTemp + marginTemp) ) {

      digitalWrite (dryer, switchOff);
      }
      // turn on heater if below max. Temp
      else if ( waterTemp  <  (dryTemp - marginTemp) ) {

        digitalWrite (dryer, switchOn);
        }
 
    }
    break;
   
   case complete:
     switchmode (0, "Program Selesai");  
     pressedButton = 0;
     currentPos = 1;
     updateMenu();
     currMode = progSelect;
     menuNo = 0;
     prevProg =1;
     break;
     
   case errPause:
     switchmode (0, "Program Ditunda");  
     pressedButton = 0;
     currentPos = 3;
     updateMenu();               
     currMode = standby;
     menuNo = 1;
     prevProg =1;
     break; 


  delay (100);  
}
```

Here's what I want, in dishwashing (which, actually wash the dishes) program, I want to make the cycle runs like this:

Start -> drain -> fill -> ***prewash*** -> drain -> fill -> ***wash*** -> drain -> fill -> ***rinse*** -> drain -> ***dry*** -> done.

While on the fruit one, I just want to run it like this.

Start -> drain -> fill -> ***prewash*** -> drain -> done.

Basically the program before I 'mess' it, well, the program went well on only 'wash', without the additional pre-wash and rinse.

How can I implement the cycle like so? I'm looking online for references, but unfortunately there's no explaining on how can I use multiple modes, mostly just running on one fixed mode. I'm kind of confused with that so far.

Any recommendation and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn about state machines (FSMs).  Way too much code.  Learn how to ask a proper question here.

Comment: @TomServo that's the thing that I actually wanna reduce, I know it feels too much code inside.

And noted, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer because there are countless ways to approach it, but it's an assigned project so there might be specific patterns you're supposed to demonstrate

*I'm going to assume this is supposed to show OOP fundamentals, so I'll avoid stuff like method references and task communication primitives (which is how I would probably implement a lot of this normally)

I would start with a simple interface that defines all the things the dishwasher can do in a "physical" sense, so drain/wash/heat up/ etc.:

```
class Dishwasher{
 setWaterTemp(temperature) //True starts prewash, false ends prewash
 setDraining(enabled) //True starts draining, false ends draining
 setPrewash(enabled) //True starts prewash, false ends prewash 
 setDrying(enabled)
}
```

Then define a cycle with how long it should take, and what it does to the dishwasher:

```
class CycleAction{
 int howLongToRun;
 virtual void run(dishwasher);
}
```

For example:

```
class PrewashAction{
 constructor(howLongToRun)
 override void run(dw){
  dw.setPrewashing(true)
  vTaskDelay(howLongToRun)
  dw.setPrewashing(false)
 }
}
```

```
class TemperatureAction{
 constructor(howLongToRun, whatTempToUse)
 override void run(dw){
  dw.setTemperature(whatTempToUse)
  vTaskDelay(howLongToRun)
 }
}
```

```
class DrainAction{
 constructor(howLongToRun)
 override void run(dw){
  dw.setDraining(true)
  vTaskDelay(howLongToRun)
  dw.setDraining(false)
 }
}
```

Now we can define a Program as a list of actions:

```
class WashProgram{
  virtual vector<CycleAction> getActions()
  int startingTime;

  void startCycle(dishwasher){
    startingTime = currentTime
    Loop Through GetActions
      action.run();
  }

  getTotalTime(){
    totalTime = 0
    Loop Through this->getActions()
      totalTime += action.
  }

 
  int remainingTime(){
    return currentTime - startingTime
  }
}
```

Now your Programs are easy to define and update:

```
class FruitWashProgram : WashProgram{
 override void getActions(){
   return {
     SetTemperatureAction(100 degrees),
     DrainAction(2 minutes),
     FillAction(2 minutes),
     PrewashAction(3 minutes),
     DrainAction(2 minutes)
   }
 }
}
```

```
class QuickHotCycle : WashProgram{
 override void getActions(){
   return {
     SetTemperatureAction(250 degrees),
     DrainAction(1 minutes),
     FillAction(1 minutes),
     WashAction(1 minutes),
     DrainAction(2 minutes)
   }
 }
}
```

```
class QuickCold : WashProgram{
 override void getActions(){
   return {
     SetTemperatureAction(60 degrees),
     DrainAction(1 minutes),
     FillAction(1 minutes),
     WashAction(1 minutes),
     DrainAction(2 minutes)
   }
 }
}
```

Now there is a *ton* of room for improvement, but I leave that as an exercise for you. Some things to think about:

- A real washing machine has "fuzzy logic", each step won't take a predefined amount of time but will depend on factors like how hot the tap water was when it started. You could replicate that by adding an "estimate" function to CycleAction
- Some of the programs will be very similar. QuickHot and QuickCold for example. Maybe you can make a QuickProgram, then extend that with specific temperatures for Hot and Cold
- Maybe certain steps need something to have happened before running. For example, you don't want to dry unless a drain has occurred. You could enforce that in a "validate" function somewhere, or add a way for the dishwasher to communicate it's in an error state

I used psuedo-code that doesn't really match any language, so if you need me to clarify anything just drop a comment and I'll explain as best as I can

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the pseudocode itself are actually really helpful to really simplify of what I wrote. Totally agree on how hard it is to actually implement it as it got so much variances between program that I see as references.

Actually, all those 4 dishwashing programs are the exact same, just with different time and temperature control.